# Red and yellow insect found in kitchen in Conrad, Montana (USA)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Beetle found in our kitchen in Conrad, Montana (USA) on 3/13/19:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a stink bug in the superfamily [Pentatomoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomoidea) of the true bugs (i.e., order [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera)).

Specifically, your specimen appears to be [***Perillus bioculatus***](https://ippc2.orst.edu/potato/stinkbugs.pdf) or the **two-spotted stink bug**.

[image]

<sup>Photo Credit: [Margarethe brummermann (2008)](https://bugguide.net/node/view/205662)</sup>

You can see additional photos including those demonstrating the species's various yellow vs red color morphs [here](https://www.opsu.edu/Academics/SciMathNurs/NaturalScience/PlantsInsectsOfGoodwell/heteroptera/pentatomidae/pent13.html).

According to the [Integrated Plant Protection Center at Oregon State University](https://ippc2.orst.edu/potato/stinkbugs.pdf) [my emphasis and links]:

> Mature nymphs of the two spotted stink bug are about 8 to 9 mm long. Adults range in length from 10 to 12 mm. Nymphs may [be] **pale yellow or reddishorange with a distinct black "Y-shaped" marking on the [pronotum](https://bugguide.net/node/view/111902) and two black spots on the [thorax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorax_(insect_anatomy))**.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perillus_bioculatus), this species is usually a beneficial predator (especially of the Colorado potato beetle), but early nymph stages feed by sucking on potato stems. The trade-off, I would guess, is worth it.

- In fact, the color variation in this species (namely the shift from white/yellow to red) that my earlier link shows photos of is a result of a higher diet of potato beetles. [[Source](https://bugguide.net/node/view/92830), taken from p 99 in McPherson's 1992 book *The Pentatomoidea (Hemiptera) of Northeastern North America*].

[image]

<sup>Source: [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/13491)</sup>

Their range, according to [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/13491) is southern Canada, the U.S. and into Mexico.

Comment: I was gobbling cherries one day and I ate a cherry with a stink bug which defended itself on my tongue. It was a bit hot and a bit indescribably chemical. wasn't a major worry though, i had forgotten about it after a while. don't eat them :D their defense works you spew them out haha.